# Apparmor prevents access to certificate bundle for IKEv2 VPN

Tags: network-manager, vpn, apparmor

I am trying to get a Strongswan / IKEV2 VPN set up on Ubuntu 23.04.
I have the Network Manager plugin compiled and working.
When I attempt the connection, I get the below error in syslog, that it is unable to open the certificate bundle.
Based on the log it appears Apparmor is blocking the access.

How do I fix it so Apparmor will allow access to the file?

```
2023-10-12T22:07:00.546588-04:00 fafnir charon: 10[CFG] received stroke: add connection '3c204271-9b89-4f25-85b8-3e13d53e6bde'
2023-10-12T22:07:00.546660-04:00 fafnir charon: 10[CFG] added configuration '3c204271-9b89-4f25-85b8-3e13d53e6bde'
2023-10-12T22:07:01.492277-04:00 fafnir charon: 12[CFG] rereading secrets
2023-10-12T22:07:01.492891-04:00 fafnir charon: 12[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'
2023-10-12T22:07:01.492904-04:00 fafnir charon: 12[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets'
2023-10-12T22:07:01.492915-04:00 fafnir charon: 12[LIB]   opening '/home/alan/pki2/client_fafnir.p12' failed: Permission denied
2023-10-12T22:07:01.492949-04:00 fafnir charon: 12[LIB] building CRED_CONTAINER - PKCS12 failed, tried 3 builders
2023-10-12T22:07:01.492960-04:00 fafnir charon: 12[CFG]   loading credentials from '/home/alan/pki2/client_fafnir.p12' failed
2023-10-12T22:07:01.495808-04:00 fafnir charon: 13[CFG] received stroke: initiate '3c204271-9b89-4f25-85b8-3e13d53e6bde'
2023-10-12T22:07:01.496243-04:00 fafnir kernel: [217471.389372] audit: type=1400 audit(1697162821.489:404): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="/usr/lib/ipsec/charon" name="/home/alan/pki2/client_fafnir.p12" pid=913258 comm="charon" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=1000
```

Comment: You write you have the strongSwan NM plugin working, but the log shows that you are not using that but the charon daemon and the stroke interface instead. So which one do you want to use? And since you already created a symlink to the file in /etc/ipsec.d, why not copy the file there in the first place?

Comment: The NM plugin is working, because if it was not, the display would say "unable to load plugin"

Comment: The file is not in /etc/ipsec.d, its in my home directory, as I was trying to trouble shoot permissions issues.

Comment: I copied the machine cert to /etc/ipsec.d/certs and it no longer complains about permissions, but there is something else going on with the set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied cert bundle to /etc/ipsec.d/certs and that resolved permission issue.